# nth-child conversion to IE support

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, css-selectors

I want the following (every 5 element with the class ".span-tag") to be compatible with IE 7/8

```
.taggar .row-fluid .span-tag:nth-child(5n),
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work so probably I'm doing it wrong:

```
.taggar .row-fluid .span-tag:first-child + .span-tag .span-tag .span-tag .span-tag {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="action-container container taggar">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3 span-tag">
            <a href="#"><div class="tag label btn-tag tags"><span>foo1</span></div><span class="votes">x 61</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 span-tag">
            <a href=""><div class="tag label btn-tag tags"><span>foo2</span></div><span class="votes">x 52</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 span-tag">
            <a href=""><div class="tag label btn-tag tags"><span>foo3</span></div><span class="votes">x 387</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 span-tag">
            <a href=""><div class="tag label btn-tag tags"><span>foo4</span></div><span class="votes">x 343</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 span-tag">
            <a href=""><div class="tag label btn-tag tags"><span>foo5</span></div><span class="votes">x 434</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 span-tag">
            <a href=""><div class="tag label btn-tag tags"><span>foo6</span></div><span class="votes">x 4</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 span-tag">
            <a href=""><div class="tag label btn-tag tags"><span>foo7</span></div><span class="votes">x 134</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 span-tag">
            <a href=""><div class="tag label btn-tag tags"><span>foo8</span></div><span class="votes">x 32</span></a>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think  this can be done without using nth-child

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your question, but you can use [a link](http://selectivizr.com/) - selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without using nth-child be be very very verbose (You would have to target each 5n-th case separately) -

If you know the upper limit of the amount of span-tag classes - then it might be viable this way, otherwise - you're out of luck. :

```
.span-tag:first-child + .span-tag + .span-tag + .span-tag + .span-tag { /* 5 times */
    margin-left: 0;
}

.span-tag:first-child + .span-tag + ... + .span-tag { /* 10 times */
    margin-left: 0;
}

.span-tag:first-child + .span-tag + ... + .span-tag { /* 15 times */
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

etc